# how to send email with log4j SMTP appender

Tags: java, spring, log4net

I want send email to email group only once after I finish the java task.

in log4j properties, I am able to send email,but is triggering email for every log statement.

But my requirement is that to send email after all tasks are completed, meaning start java program, do some processing which will have multiple log statements, then send email.

Below is my log4j smtp properties list.

```
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, sendMail  
#log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender  
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d{mm:ss} (%F:%M:%L)%n%m%n%n  
#log4j.appender.sendMail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender  
##log4j.appender.sendMail.Threshold=WARN  
#log4j.appender.sendMail.To=xx@domain.com   
#log4j.appender.sendMail.From=xx@domain.com  
#log4j.appender.sendMail.SMTPHost=10.13.16.57
#log4j.appender.sendMail.Subject=Log4J Message  
#log4j.appender.sendMail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
#log4j.appender.sendMail.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n  
#log4j.appender.sendMail.BufferSize=1  
#log4j.appender.sendMail.SMTPDebug=true
```

Comment: Since you don't want to send an email for every log statement - just one email at the end, is there any reason why you're using Log4J to accomplish this? Would you not be better to use Spring's `JavaMailSender`?

Comment: Hi Will Keeling, I don't want to send email for every log because I am  verifying different URLs and folder permissions, and the batch job has to send email every 40 min. so definitely sending separate email for every log does not look good in my opinion. could you please give me some insight into JavaMailSender

Answer (score 0):

Define your log4j configuration in XML and add a logger element to use as logger name.

see [log4j XML format](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) and [Log4j config](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
   <to value="to@domain.com" />
   <from value="from@domain.com" />
   <subject value="test logging message" />
   <smtpHost value="SMTPServer.domain.com" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
   </layout>
</appender>   
<logger name="sendMail" additivity="false">
   <level value="info" />
   <appender-ref ref="mailAppender" />
</logger>
```

In your code:

```
private static Logger LOG_MAIL = Logger.getLogger("sendMail");
```

Comment: without XML format,it can be done ? like in log4j.properties file? I have currently log4j properties in .properties file. But my question is i want to send email only once. does this configuration send email once or sends email for every LOG_MAIL.log?

Comment: @mahesh Yes you can. You already defined the root logger. Add another one like `log4j.sendMail = mailSender`. This should do the trick.

Comment: sorry I did not get that adding another one ? you mean another rootLooger or appender?

Comment: @mahesh you can have multiple loggers and appender. Use `log4j.logger.sendMail = mailSender` to define the logger sendMail and assign the smtp appender to it. (sry, long time I used the old property format)

Comment: thanks, I already have the mailSender in the post : #log4j.appender.sendMail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender, you suggest to add one more?

Comment: My main request is that how to send email only once not every time log the message

Comment: @mahesh Oh I see. Well, since you have now another logger that is attached to you mailSender Appender, you can aggregation the mail and send it in one log event.

Comment: thanks  Hannes, is there any predefined library to aggregate the log events or just follow java standard methods like Stringbuffer or whatever and then use one mailserndlog.log() once? if that is the case , I can better use javamail with spring integration rather log4j

Comment: @mahesh I would write to a separate log file and send it via attachment.

Comment: thanks Hannes, but my client wants it be in email body as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to send one email at the end of the batch run, you may be better to aggregate all of the messages into some sort of large string, and then use Spring's `JavaMailSender` to send a single email.

You can find [various articles](http://springtips.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/send-e-mail-using-spring-and-javamail.html) on sending email using `JavaMailSender` but essentially you'd need to first configure an instance of it in your Spring config:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="mail_host"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>
    <property name="username" value="mail_username"/>
    <property name="password" value="mail_password"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then in your client (batch job or whatever it happens to be), you can specify an autowired field for the `JavaMailSender`:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;
```

And then it would just be a case of creating and sending the message:

```
SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
message.setTo(to);
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(body); // Your aggregated messages
mailSender.send(message);
```

That's the basics - but you'll find plenty of other articles and documentation discussing it in more detail around the web.